# intercepting declarative XML UI values in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I would prefer to do most UI layout and set view properties in XML but have run into times when I need to override these values in code before rendering the view.

I can continue to do this after the layout/viewgroup has been constructed from the processed XML files but am wondering if there is a better way.

I know which property values need to be overwritten before the UI is constructed.  Is there an event / pipeline I can extent that would allow me to inject a new value for a property while it is being constructed by the system?

Not sure if this more efficient - just thinking about alternative solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a pipeline exists (I don't think it does) it will probably not gain you more in terms of efficiency.

When you compile your application, each XML layout file is compiled into a View resource, which are loaded from your application code (mostly in the `onCreate()` method of Activity).

This basically means after compiling, there's no XML to be edited/injected.

Comment: When the compiled view resource is being reconstituted into an object, or when the new view object graph is about to be added application, is there any opportunity to be notified / inject my own code to insert new values?

Comment: I am not aware of that. I just think that injecting in the generated view object graph, compare to overriding values in onCreate() won't gain any performance.